# Direcionar com htaccess sem alterar a url

Tags: php, htaccess

Colegas.

Tenho um sistema que está dentro do seguinte diretório. www.site.com.br/crm/sistema/ Gostaria que ao digitar www.site.com.br/crm, fosse direcionado para a pasta sistema, mas sem alterar a url, continuando www.site.com.br/crm. Tenho o seguinte código abaixo, mas não está funcionando:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com.br/crm$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sistema/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sistema/$1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com.br/crm$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sistema/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

coloque um arquivo .htaccess na pasta "crm": http://www.site.com.br/crm/

Como o código abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^crm/(.*)$ ./sistema/$1
```

E dentro da pasta "sistema", coloque outro arquivo .htaccess, com as regras como no exemplo abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /crm/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R,L]

# inicio --------------- suas regras aqui -------------------#

RewriteRule ^index$ index.php
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
RewriteRule ^exemplo-id-(.*)$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^pg/(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1
```